# Ordinal scale category10 mapping everything to same color

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a scatterplot with some dynamic scales, I have some data mapped to linar color scale and it works perfectly well. I tried setting up an ordinal color scale for some discrete data but it outputs the same color for every value.

Here's the scale funciton

```
var cScale = {

linear : function(arr, numFunc ){

    return d3.scale.linear()
        .domain( d3.extent(arr, numFunc) )
        .range([colorRange.min,colorRange.max])

},

ordinal : function(arr, ordinalFunc){
    return d3.scale.category10()
        // .domain(d3.extent(arr, ordinalFunc))
    }
}
```

Used as follows

```
 window.cScaleFunc = cScale.ordinal

 fillCircleRef
    .attr("r", function(d){
        if(movieFilter(d))return 0;
        return rScaleFunc(arr, rDataFunc)(rDataFunc(d));
    })
    .attr("fill", function(d){
        return cScaleFunc(arr, cDataFunc)(cDataFunc(d));
    })
```

output

> **#1f77b4 bollywood, #1f77b4 hollywood**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  are returning a new instance `d3.scale.category10()` everytime ordinal is called

```
ordinal : function(arr, ordinalFunc){
    return d3.scale.category10()
        // .domain(d3.extent(arr, ordinalFunc))
    }
}
```

Do it this way:

```
var cScale = {
myScale : d3.scale.category10(),
linear : function(arr, numFunc ){

    return d3.scale.linear()
        .domain( d3.extent(arr, numFunc) )
        .range([colorRange.min,colorRange.max])

},

ordinal : function(arr, ordinalFunc){
    return this.myScale;//now there is a single scale and we dont inititialize evrytime its called
        // .domain(d3.extent(arr, ordinalFunc))
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I did 
    var contextScaleC = cScaleFunc(arr, cDataFunc);

    fillCircleRef
        .attr("fill", function(d){
            return contextScaleC(cDataFunc(d));
        })

Does this look ok ?

Comment: yeah you have written window.cScaleFunc = cScale.ordinal
So everytime cScaleFunc(arr, cDataFunc) is called it will make a new d3.scale.category10()

Comment: hmm I am creating other scales dynamically as well, based on change in data and wanted to maintain a standard feel amongst the scales ( I realize I don't need new instance everytime for category10 ) but is that really such a bad thing to do ?

Comment: Ok gotcha! but if every time you create a new d3.scale.category10()  it does not know if "hollywood" o r "bollywood" is assigned this color #1f77b4 so the above issue :)